# Blue background to my RTF fields

Tags: xpages

When my Rich Text field renders on my xPage, the background is blue.  I assume it has something to do with OneUI.  How do I turn that off.  Just want a white background.

I've set the actual RTF to force it's background white but now there is a blue edging around it.

thanks 
clem

Comment: just use firebug to find out which class or id that set it as blue and override it

Comment: Hi Thomas.  Thanks for the reply.  In Chrome, in Show Properties, there's this "class:'domino-par--indent'".  I have no idea where that's coming from.

Comment: a good way yo troubleshoot this is to add a rt field to an empty xpages and see if you get the same problem there. I have never managed to get a blue rt brackground on my xpages. also test different machine and webbrowsers

Comment: Great minds!! ;-)  I did try that and DO NOT see the blue background.  Now I have to figure out where the heck it's coming from!  Driving me nuts.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such "blue" property by default for an RTF. And I'm not aware that without changing the OneUI theme, this is a normal behaviour. 
So either the OneUI theme has been changed directly, or there is a theme that extends the used them, or a background property is set via CSS an !important parameter.